# Is it possible to mount disk to gke pod and compute engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to mount disk to gke pod and compute engine at the same time.

I have a ubunut disk of 10 gb

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-demo
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10G
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    name: pv-claim-demo
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: pv-test1

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-demo
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10G
```

deploment.yaml

```
spec:
  containers:
    - image: wordpress
      name: wordpress
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
      volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /app/logs
  volumes:
    - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pv-claim-demo
```

The idea is to mount the logs files generated by pod to disk and access it from compute engine.
I cannot use NFS or hostpath to solve the problem. The other challenge is multiple pod will be writting to same pv.

Comment: Adding everything you are trying to get a storage solution that could be mounted to `GKE` and `GCE` at the same time with ability to be written by multiple "hosts"? Could you tell is there any particular reason that `NFS` like Filestore cannot be used? Have you checked `GCS Buckets` by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

> The other challenge is multiple pod will be writing to same PV.

Yes, this does not work well, unless you have a storage class similar to NFS. The default [storageClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) in Google Kubernetes Engine only support [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) ReadWriteOnce when dynamically provisioned - so only one replica can mount it.

> The idea is to mount the logs files generated by pod to disk and access it from compute engine.

This is not a recommended solution for logs when using Kubernetes. An app on Kubernetes should follow the [12 factor principles](https://12factor.net/), and for this problem there is a specific item about [logs](https://12factor.net/logs) - the app should log to `stdout`. For apps that does not follow the 12 factor principles, this can be solved by a [sidecar that tails the log files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-sidecar-container-with-the-logging-agent) and then print them on `stdout`.

Logs that are printed to `stdout` is typically forwarded by the platform to a log collection system - as a service. So this is not anything the app developer need to be responsible for.

For how logs is handled by the platform in Google Kubernetes Engine, see [Google Cloud Operations suite for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke)

Comment: It could be beneficiary to add this link about `--multi-writer` support: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164841448

Answer (score 0):

You can't write many on Persistent disk. If you set your disk in read only, many can read on it (but not write, don't match your use case).

The only solution for this is to use NFS compliant storage. On Google Cloud, it's [filestore service](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs). It's exactly designed for your use case and you have [tutorial for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares)

Answer (score 0):

Better use the [Google Cloud's operations suite for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke) (formerly known as StackDriver).

There would be two API, which can be used to access from GCE:

- [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3)
- [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/apis)